# Save fileds changes with ajax in laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I want to change some parts of my data from index page without loading edit page with Ajax.
For example my reviews has `status` where value is `0` or `1` and also `comment` section. I want to change these values from my index page.

[image]

All the code i have is simply my index method only, where i load my list

```
public function index()
    {
      $ratings = Rating::orderby('id', 'desc')->paginate(10);
      return view('admin.ratings.index', compact('ratings'));
    }
```

I need help to make my index page as a form with Ajax in order to edit from there but not to use my `Update` method because I'll need it for my `edit.blade.php` (maybe add another method in my controller?)

Thanks.

Comment: where is your ajax code? can we have a look at it

Comment: @usrNotFound As I mentioned I don't have any Ajax code because I don't know how to make it `All the code i have is simply my index method only, where i load my list`

Comment: Ok sure I think you will need an update endpoint that sends post request when your status is updated using ajax, or else you can have seperate controller call UpdatePostStatusController with store method that only updates stats of the post and send your ajax request

Comment: @usrNotFound I have lot's of controllers I think i'll go with your first suggestion, would you mind help me with that?

Comment: I sure can but with the first approach what will happen if you want to update your post. What endpoint would you use?

Comment: ok here is more explanation: when I change switch button status of my review will change and I'll get success alert. And for comment when i click on note textarea field will show and I can edit text then when i hit enter on keyboard will save the new data. that's what I try to approach.

Comment: check the answer. This includes how to update comment/post status

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159102/discussion-between-usrnotfound-and-mafortis).

Comment: To deal with AJAX, first, don't think it in AJAX! Think it as ordinary form that submits data to an action. So, you have to create in the controller an action that will change the status and a view with a form that updates the status value. After being sure it works fine, using jQuery AJAX from the view you will be able to perform the task by submitting data to your action.

Comment: @SaidbakR Good point bro. then what? I mean after new form succeeded to work?

Comment: @mafortis In other words, replace each status toggle button with a form tag that its action points to your controller action and supply it with radio button element. Then using jQuery bind change event that posts that form to its action -ordinary i.e the page is reloaded- then implement jQuery AJAX with the change event. Checkout [**this resource**](http://formvalidation.io/examples/ajax-submit/) to help you to use jQuery AJAX.

Comment: did you get others working?

Comment: @usrNotFound no :(

Comment: hop back to chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159102/discussion-between-usrnotfound-and-mafortis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need a controller that updates the post status. As discussed it totally up to you want you want to do.

My suggestion is to create a new controller called UpdatePostStatusController and then have update method that takes post id and the status either 1 or 0 and update it.

Your index file should have javascript that gets triggred everytime you change the status like so

checkbox html

```
<input type="checkbox" data-uuid="{{ $post->id }}" class="update" @if($post->status) checked @endif/>
```

Now your ajax should

```
 $('.update').change(function() {

  data = {'status' : this.checked }
  post_id =  $(this).data('uuid');

//do your ajax post request here here
}
```